# Sorting Date is not working as expected using XSLT

Tags: xml, sorting, date, xslt

I have a requirement where I need to sort different block of XML based on their dates and put them in different tags. So far I am able to achieve this using numbers. But whenever I try to sort it by dates it doesn't work. I tried this with different data-types as well. But wasn't able to success. Any pointers will be great.

XML:

```
response status="200">
        <classes>
            <classdetsils>
                <name>Learn12</name>
                <date1>20161115</date1>
            </classdetsils>
            <classdetsils>
                <name>Learn12</name>
                <date1>20161114</date1>
            </classdetsils>
            <classdetsils>
                <name>Learn13</name>
                <date1>20161117</date1>
            </classdetsils>
            <classdetsils>
                <name>Learn14</name>
                <date1>20161116</date1>
            </classdetsils>
            <classdetsils>
                <name>Learn15</name>
                <date1>20161113</date1>
            </classdetsils>
        </classes>
    </response>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"  extension-element-prefixes="dp"  exclude-result-prefixes="dp">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="vN" select="20161116"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <test1>
        <a>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="response/classes/classdetsils[date1 &gt; $vN]" />
            <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="date1" data-type="number"/>
        </a>
        <b>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="response/classes/classdetsils[date1 &lt; $vN]" />
            <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="date1" data-type="number"/>
        </b>
    </test1>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="classdetsils">
    <name>
        <xsl:value-of select="name" />
    </name>
    <date>
        <xsl:value-of select="date1" />
    </date>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<test1 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
<a>
    <name>Learn13</name>
    <date>20161117</date>
</a>
<b>
    <name>Learn12</name>
    <date>20161115</date>
    <name>Learn12</name>
    <date>20161114</date>
    <name>Learn15</name>
    <date>20161113</date>
</b></test1>
```

This works fine as the date1 fields is a number now. But if I change the value of date1 to a xs:date type in the XML i.e.: 20161115 becomes 2016-11-15 and does the change in XSLT as well, it doesn't seems to work. So the XML becomes:

```
response status="200">
    <classes>
        <classdetsils>
            <name>Learn12</name>
            <date1>2016-11-15</date1>
        </classdetsils>
        <classdetsils>
            <name>Learn12</name>
            <date1>2016-11-14</date1>
        </classdetsils>
        <classdetsils>
            <name>Learn13</name>
            <date1>2016-11-17</date1>
        </classdetsils>
        <classdetsils>
            <name>Learn14</name>
            <date1>2016-11-16</date1>
        </classdetsils>
        <classdetsils>
            <name>Learn15</name>
            <date1>2016-11-13</date1>
        </classdetsils>
    </classes>
</response>
```

And the XSLT is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"  extension-element-prefixes="dp"  exclude-result-prefixes="dp">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="vN" select="2016-11-16"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <test1>
        <a>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="response/classes/classdetsils[date1 &gt; $vN]" />
            <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="date1" data-type="number"/>
        </a>
        <b>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="response/classes/classdetsils[date1 &lt; $vN]" />
            <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="date1" data-type="number"/>
        </b>
    </test1>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="classdetsils">
    <name>
        <xsl:value-of select="name" />
    </name>
    <date>
        <xsl:value-of select="date1" />
    </date>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output becomes null:

```
<test1 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
<a />
<b /></test1>
```

I think I am making some silly mistake with the data-types. Any pointers will be helpful.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it using the below:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="response/classes/classdetsils[number(translate(date1‌​, '-', '')) &gt; number(translate($vN, '-', '')) or number(translate(date1, '-', '')) = number(translate($vN, '-', ''))]"> <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="xs:date(date1)"/> </xsl:apply-templates>
```

I can provided the XSLT if any one needs it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `xsl:sort` needs to be a child of the `xsl:apply-templates`, and the `xs:date` format can't be sorted as an number but only as a string or (assuming support for XSLT/XPath 2.0) as `xs:date`:

```
       <xsl:apply-templates select="response/classes/classdetsils[date1 &gt; $vN]">
        <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="xs:date(date1)"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
```

However, given your current code, you will need to make sure you pass in the date as a string and convert to an `xs:date` and also change the predicate:

```
<xsl:param name="vN" select="'2016-11-16'"/>
<xsl:variable name="vD" select="xs:date($vN)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <test1>
        <a>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="response/classes/classdetsils[xs:date(date1) &gt; $vD]">
              <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="xs:date(date1)"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </a>
        <b>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="response/classes/classdetsils[xs:date(date1) &lt; $vD]">
              <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="xs:date(date1)" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </b>
    </test1>
</xsl:template>
```

Then with an XSLT 2.0 processor that should do and does for me at http://xsltransform.net/jxDigUK.

As an alternative, sort and compare as strings (comparing I think will also only work as a string with XSLT/XPath 2.0):

```
<xsl:param name="vN" select="'2016-11-16'"/>


<xsl:template match="/">
    <test1>
        <a>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="response/classes/classdetsils[date1 &gt; $vN]">
              <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="date1" data-type="text"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </a>
        <b>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="response/classes/classdetsils[date1 &lt; $vN]">
              <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="date1" data-type="text" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </b>
    </test1>
</xsl:template>
```

http://xsltransform.net/naZXpXM

Comment: Note also that in the common case where all the dates are in YYYY-MM-DD format (four-digit year, no sign, no timezone) and you use a well-behaved default collation, sorting dates as strings works perfectly well and is probably faster than converting them first to xs:date and then sorting as dates. If your transformation is schema-aware and the attributes are already typed as xs:date then that's a different matter, of course.

Comment: @Martin-Honnen I did tried that, but that didn't worked either.    `<xsl:apply-templates select="response/classes/classdetsils[date1 &gt; $vN or date1 = $vN ]" >
   <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="xs:date(date1)"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>`

Comment: See the edit, the parameter/variable needs to be changed too and the comparison in the predicate needs to be adapted as well. Then, at least with XSLT 2.0 you should be able to do that. With XSLT 1.0 you might need to use `number(translate(date1, '-', '')) > number(translate($vN, '-', '')`

Comment: I have tried this now with version 1. http://xsltransform.net/ehVYZNH/1 But somehow the less than equation is not working and greater than equation shows all the records.

Comment: What do you expect `<xsl:param name="vN" select="2016-11-16"/>` to do? It is computing `2016-11-16` i.e. `2016` minus `11` minus `16`. So that whole comparison later can't make sense, you will need to quote that parameter value as I did in `<xsl:param name="vN" select="'2016-11-16'"/>`.

Comment: Seems like some problem with DataPower processor. Let me raise this with them.